# Update postman collection programatically

Tags: azure-devops, automation, postman, devops

My application generates Open API/Swagger specification file. It may have new API additions/updates. I want to have an automated script/job which uploads/updates this specification into existing postman collection. I looked in Powershell, Terraform, Postman APIs but they don't support it.

Is there any other way to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 3):

The postman has an official tool called [swagger2-postman2-converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger2-postman2-converter) to update postman.

And **the official blog [Sync your specs](https://blog.postman.com/sync-your-specs/)** describes in detail how to update collections using this tool.

Here are the detailed steps. I am using the [sample code](https://github.com/loopDelicious/converter) provided by postman. You can replace your file with the corresponding file in the sample.

1. If you don't have a Postman API key, go to your [account settings](https://web.postman.co/settings/me/api-keys) and generate one. Click [Postman API](https://learning.postman.com/docs/developer/intro-api/) for detailed information.
2. Stored your key in a json file. The `_secrets.json` file in this sample.
3. Run the GET API to get your `collection_uid` and `collection_id` and update the `config.js` file.

Get All Collections: `https://api.getpostman.com/collections`

Get Single Collection: `https://api.getpostman.com/collections/{{collection_uid}}`

4. Run `npm install fs swagger2-postman2-converter` to install the dependencies.
5. Run `node converter.js`
6. Run PUT API to update your collection.

PUT Update Collection: `https://api.getpostman.com/collections/{{collection_uid}}`

**After you have run it once, if you have any updates to your swagger.json file, you only need to perform steps 5 and 6.**